# Groupby Rowwise in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame as below:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'variable':["A","A","B","B","C","D","E","E","E","F","F","G"],'weight':[2,2,0,0,1,3,5,5,5,0,0,4]})


Out[129]: 
   variable  weight
0         A       2
1         A       2
2         B       0
3         B       0
4         C       1
5         D       3
6         E       5
7         E       5
8         E       5
9         F       0
10        F       0
11        G       4
```

I would like to create new column, based on groups of `variable`, The value of New column is base on column `weight` and ***itself***.

In R : I can easily using `rowwise` from `dplyr` to get the desired output

```
library(dplyr)
test <-
  data.frame(
    variable    = c("A","A","B","B","C","D","E","E","E","F","F","G"), 
    weight      = c(2,2,0,0,1,3,5,5,5,0,0,4)
  )

test%>%group_by(variable)%>%rowwise()%>%mutate(Var=ifelse (weight==2,1,ifelse(.Last.value ==1|weight>1,0,NA)))
```

and the expected out put as below:

```
   variable weight   Var
     <fctr>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1        A      2     1
 2        A      2     1
 3        B      0    NA
 4        B      0    NA
 5        C      1    NA
 6        D      3     0
 7        E      5     0
 8        E      5     0
 9        E      5     0
10        F      0    NA
11        F      0    NA
12        G      4     0
```

How can I achieve this in Python ?

***EDIT : Above R method are wrong too***

My approach :

```
l1=[]
for i in df.variable.unique():
    temp=df.loc[df.variable==i]
    l2 = []
    for j in range(len(temp)):
        print(i,j)

        if temp.iloc[j,1]<=2 :
            l2.append(1)
        elif temp.iloc[j,1]>2 and j==0:
            l2.append('ERROR')
        elif temp.iloc[j,1]>2 and j > 0 :
            if l2[j - 1] == 1:
                l2.append(1)
            else:
                l2.append(0)
        print(l2)
    l1.extend(l2)
df['NEW']=l1
```

---

*Data Input*

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'variable':["A","A","B","B","C","D","E","E","E","F","F","G"],'weight':[2,2,0,0,1,3,3,5,5,0,0,4]})
```

---

out put

```
df['NEW']=l1
df
Out[232]: 
   variable  weight    NEW
0         A       2      1
1         A       2      1
2         B       0      1
3         B       0      1
4         C       1      1
5         D       3  ERROR
6         E       3  ERROR
7         E       5      0
8         E       5      0
9         F       0      1
10        F       0      1
11        G       4  ERROR
```

Comment: I'm failing to see where the `groupby` plays a role.  `df.assign(Var=df.weight.eq(2).mul(1).mask(df.weight.le(1)))`

Comment: I'm not able to understand the logic behind the combination... can you explain?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ will open a new question

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Sorry , I made the update , and already accept Pir's answer , I appreciated both of your guys' time!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Groupby!
Let me know if I interpretted this correctly.

---

**Option 1**

```
df.assign(Var=df.weight.eq(2).mul(1).mask(df.weight.le(1))) 

   variable  weight  Var
0         A       2  1.0
1         A       2  1.0
2         B       0  NaN
3         B       0  NaN
4         C       1  NaN
5         D       3  0.0
6         E       5  0.0
7         E       5  0.0
8         E       5  0.0
9         F       0  NaN
10        F       0  NaN
11        G       4  0.0
```

---

**Option 2**

```
df.assign(Var=np.array([np.nan, 1, 0])[np.searchsorted([1, 2], df.weight.values)])

   variable  weight  Var
0         A       2  1.0
1         A       2  1.0
2         B       0  NaN
3         B       0  NaN
4         C       1  NaN
5         D       3  0.0
6         E       5  0.0
7         E       5  0.0
8         E       5  0.0
9         F       0  NaN
10        F       0  NaN
11        G       4  0.0
```

---

**Option 3**

```
df.assign(Var=np.array([1, 0, np.nan])[np.sign(df.weight.values - 2)])

   variable  weight  Var
0         A       2  1.0
1         A       2  1.0
2         B       0  NaN
3         B       0  NaN
4         C       1  NaN
5         D       3  0.0
6         E       5  0.0
7         E       5  0.0
8         E       5  0.0
9         F       0  NaN
10        F       0  NaN
11        G       4  0.0
```

Comment: It is my fault, My sample data can not distinct that.

Comment: No worries, I'll update my answer when I see new data and understand the problem.

Comment: Let me open a new question ~ sorry for that , cause your answer solve the output exactly

Comment: I made the update , Accutally , I was asking by one of my co-worker... and feel stuck for whole night ...